# I would like to change a part of the main link using a selector

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I would like to change a part of the main link using a selector. For example:

There is a main link that we are redirected to by default, but, if we select an option on the selector, it will add a complement on the link, redirecting us to another page.

How can I get it to work the way I would like to?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#buttonId").click(function() {
    var instagram_value = $('#instagram').val();
    var instagram_name = $('#instagram :selected').text();
    
    window.location = "https://instagram.com/" + "+instagram_name + " / " +instagram_name +" / " + country_value;
  });
});
```

```html
<form method="get" action="">
  <select id="instagram">
    <option value="">Select Location</option>
    <option value="1">The Rock</option>
    <option value="2">Will Smith</option>
  </select>
  
  <button type="submiti" id="buttonId">Submit</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code has an error, possibly related to a missing quotation mark. Please edit the demo above to fix that.

Comment: Then, your question isn't clear. There are no links (anchors) in your markup. Please revise to explain better what you're trying to do.

Comment: Note that a submit button will submit the form regardless of your click handler unless you explicitly prevent that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the form to be submitted and instead just want to rediredt to another page, just set the button type to `button`:

```html
<button type="button" id="buttonId">Submit</button>
```

**Working example:**
(simplified for demonstration)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#buttonId").click(function() {
    var instagram_value = $('#instagram').val();
    var instagram_name = $('#instagram :selected').text();
    
    window.location = "https://instagram.com/" + instagram_name;
  });
});
```

```html
<form method="get" action="">
  <select id="instagram">
    <option value="">Select Location</option>
    <option value="1">The Rock</option>
    <option value="2">Will Smith</option>
  </select>
  
  <button type="button" id="buttonId">Submit</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```